# Git push new local branch to remote, without having to specify name

Tags: git

When working on patch fixes for a specific, tracked issue, our workflow looks like:

```
1. git checkout patch; git pull upstream patch; # make sure we're up-to-date
2. git checkout -b issue-435-db-integrity-exception
3. # code some awesome
4. git commit -am "Fixes issue #435"
5. git push -u origin issue-435-db-integrity-exception
```

Then we open a pull request from `origin/435` to `upstream/patch`, so that the code review can take place on GitHub/Bitbucket. Then we just start over from step #1.

**But**, though it may sound a bit whiny, it would be great if we didn't have to explicitly name the remote branch we want to create:

```
git push -u origin issue-435-db-integrity-exception
```

It's not a lot of fun to type that branch name all over again, and I disagree with changing it to just `435` or something more compact.

Is there a way to (1) force Git to push the current branch to a similarly named branch, *creating it if necessary* without explicitly naming it? Not *globally*, just an on-the-spot kind of flag.

**Or,** is it possible to (2) access the current branch in a Git alias, and write something like:

```
[alias]
    pnew = push -u origin $(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
```

(But this doesn't work - it thinks that the `--short` option is meant for `push`)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
# For Git 1.8.5+
git push origin -u @

# For older versions of Git
git push origin -u HEAD
```

By using `@` or `HEAD`, Git will push the currently checked-out branch to `origin`, and if the branch doesn't exist on `origin` yet, it will create it.

So, in your example, if you have `issue-435-db-integrity-exception` checked out, then `git push origin @` will make a new branch with the same name on `origin`.

Comment: @CraigOtis you could even make it into an alias if you want, something like `git config --global alias.magic "push origin -u head"`, then the usage would be `git magic`!

Comment: Using `@` doesn't work for me, but `head` works. Maybe something might have changed