# Git push new branch without specifying remote name gives refspec error

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to alias a push command so I don't have to type my branch name all the time, and I'm stalled at this step:
[Git push new local branch to remote, without having to specify name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106638/git-push-new-local-branch-to-remote-without-having-to-specify-name)

This command isn't working for me. I get:

```
$ git push origin -u head

error: src refspec head does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:hurtstotouchfire/repo.git'
```

This branch was created by cloning into the repo, then using `git checkout -b` to create the new branch, making a commit, and then the push command above. Is there some config necessary to use this command?

Answer (score 2):

```
git push origin -u HEAD
```

`HEAD` is a valid ref, `head` is not.